# Facebook Ads Mediation with AdMob using Expo

Tags: react-native, facebook, admob, expo, facebook-audience-network

Been struggling with Facebook ads on my app (developed using Expo managed workflow)
I never successfully display any Facebook ads and I would like to try mediating FB ads using AdMob.

I created placements on Facebook, the status is now "Waiting for bid request" and also set up the AdMob end. I can see AdMob sending bid requests to Facebook from the AdMob mediation report, but it always said no request on the Facebook end.

Does anyone successfully implement Facebook mediation on AdMob (be it a banner or interstitials)?

Many thanks!

Regards,
Rex

Comment: Hey.. Did you able to figure it out?

Comment: Not yet, how about you? I can't even get Facebook ad displayed.